# Creating a wordcloud with shiny

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, text-analysis, word-cloud

I am trying to create a wordcloud with shiny, where the cloud will change according to the selectinput. I am not able to use the variable created inside the reactive(), in renderplot. My scripts is following

```
library(shiny)
#UI
shinyUI(fluidPage(
 # Application title
 titlePanel("Word Clouds "),
 # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins
 sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     selectInput("var",
              "Choose Group:",
  choices= c("High","Low"),
  selected="Low")),

# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("Plot1")))))


# Server 
# keeping dtm inside reactive function, bec it will change with every select input  

library(shiny)
library(slam)
library(tm)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(wordcloud)
data = read.csv("abc.csv")
data = tolower(data)


shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data1 =reactive({
  sample_c=data[data$col1==input$var,]
  Corp <- Corpus(VectorSource(sample_c$desc_copy))
  dtm=TermDocumentMatrix(Corp, control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))     
  tdm.spar=removeSparseTerms(dtm, sparse=0.9)  
  ddm= rollup(tdm.spar,2,na.rm=TRUE, FUN=sum) # using slam package bec of huge data 
  m <- as.matrix(ddm)
  v <- sort(rowSums(m),decreasing=TRUE)
  d <- data.frame(word = names(v),freq=v)
  list (d1=d)})

  wordcloud_rep <- repeatable(wordcloud)

  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
   data2=data1()$d1  
   set.seed(1234)
   wordcloud_rep(words = data2$word, freq = data2$freq, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))   }) })
```

I am receiving error

> invalid cex value

again and again. I will really appreciate every help

Comment: This `Error` occurs when You have `NA's` in Your data. You should provide sample data to Your example code (you have used `abc.csv` in your code, which you havent provided) ...Additionaly on the first look on the code  You have a mistake in `renderPlot` function: it should be: `data1=data1()$d1` and NOT `data1=data()$d1`

Comment: I can assure you the data is right, and also since my reactive function is data, then in that case it should be data1=data()$d1, isn't it

Comment: Your reactive function is `data1`, at least that is what your code says: `data1 =reactive({
  sample_c=data[data$col1==input$var,]...`

Comment: oh my bad, that is 1 type error while posting on stack, I will edit it rightaway

Comment: eitherway You should provide sample data

Comment: Can you add this to the control list of the TermDocumentMatrix(): `wordLengths=c(0,Inf)`?

Comment: Even if I add remove sparse there, I will have to create other variables like rolling up via slam, so anyways the problem will persist